# Equals method in HashSet

Tags: java, collections, treeset

I am trying to understand TreeSet. I have created am Employee object and trying to add the employee object to TreeSet. to realize this I have created class called sortName, which sorts the employee objects based on name. and I have written an equals method too (just to understand the execution flow). I read that in TreeSet to add elements in some sorted we must implement comparator interface and overwrite two methods (compare and equals) ofcourse equals is optional. When i try to run the program it works, I observed that the equals method is never invoked, why is that?

Lets draw a comparison between HashSet and TreeSet. in HashSet when the hashCode is same then it checks for equals method, otherwise not. I am interested in knowing how is the working in TreeSet?
Can anyone give me a example where even equals method is invoked for TreeSet?

```
public int compare(Object Obj1, Object Obj2) {
    System.out.println("compare");
    if (Obj1 instanceof Employee19 && Obj2 instanceof Employee19) {
        Employee19 emp1=(Employee19) Obj1;
        Employee19 emp2=(Employee19) Obj2;

        return emp1.sname.compareTo(emp2.sname);
    }
    return 0;
}

public boolean equals(Object obj){
    System.out.println("equals");
    return true;
}
```

I even checked this link but that was not what I was looking...
[HashSet with two equals object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4055780/hashset-with-two-equals-object)

Comment: You can directly look into the source code. `TreeSet` doesn't uses `equals()` method, but the `compareTo` method or `compare()` method, which ever is applicable.

Comment: I tried its not working..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `TreeSet` doesn't need to use the `equals` method, because it gets all the information it needs from the `Comparator`'s `compare` method (or the `compareTo` method if it is relying on its elements being `Comparable`).  Either way can tell if elements are equivalent, if the appropriate method returns `0`.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. So at no point, the equals method is called in TreeSet. I mean for comparison.

Comment: You are correct.  The `equals` method isn't called in `TreeSet`.  As you have it, you will never see "equals" printed and you will see "compare" printed, when you call a `TreeSet` method such as `add`.