# assertEquals not comparing HashSet java

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, hashset, cascading

I am writing Unit test using Junit 4 to compare two List
I have two lists of tuples of type java.util.List

The tuple order can be different inside the List. I would like to compare these two Lists.

What i have done

```
assertEquals(new HashSet(List1), new HashSet(List2));
```

Assertion is failing saying

```
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: 
Expected :[2    second  38.46   162.417 361.583 112.331, 1  first   157.577 154.985 135.126 171.198]
Actual   :[2    second  38.46   162.417 361.583 112.331, 1  first   157.577 154.985 135.126 171.198]
```

I can't see any difference between two, how to compare this?

Edit:
Even I am comparing like

```
assertEquals(expectedCanonmap, getOutput(out));
```

it is saying

```
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: 
Expected :[1    first   157.577 154.985 135.126 171.198, 2  second  38.46   162.417 361.583 112.331]
Actual   :[1    first   157.577 154.985 135.126 171.198, 2  second  38.46   162.417 361.583 112.331]
```

Comment: What is printed is the toString() of each set. But two objects a and b having the same toString() are not necessarily equal. To be equal, a.equals(b) must return true (and vice versa). Have you implemented equals() and hashCode() in your Tuple class? Where is the code?

Comment: Also, if you want to compare two lists, why do you need to stick them into a `HashSet` before comparing? Seems rather redundant to me

Comment: +1 for @user3580294 you should just sort these lists, then run `Assert.assertEquals` for them

Comment: I have not implemented the equals() and hashCode() in TupleClass.
How to sort this list on the basis of what??

Comment: You have to override `equals()` and `hashCode()` if you expect a `HashSet` and `assertEquals()` to work.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4055780/hashset-with-two-equals-object

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3692426/hashset-does-not-seem-to-realize-that-two-objects-are-the-same